# How do you generate a group number in mysql select by a date-time range?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with records that include a DATETIME field. I would like to select the records with a group number based on a time split (6:00 AM).

For example: all records before 6:00 AM on Monday would have a group_id of 1. Any values after that until 6:00 AM on Tuesday would have a group_id of 2, and after 6:00 AM on Wednesday would have a group_id of 3, and so on.

Record example:

```
========================================
|ID   |timestamp            |value     |
========================================
|0    |2012-03-00 18:20:00  |John      |
|1    |2012-03-01 02:44:00  |Sally     |
|2    |2012-03-01 03:12:00  |Mike      |
|3    |2012-03-01 08:51:00  |Art       |
|4    |2012-03-02 01:20:00  |Kate      |
|5    |2012-03-03 01:20:00  |Susan     |
|6    |2012-03-05 07:46:00  |Sam       |
========================================
```

Goal:

```
===================================================
|ID   |timestamp            |value     |group_id  |
===================================================
|0    |2012-03-00 18:20:00  |John      |1         |
|1    |2012-03-01 02:44:00  |Sally     |1         |
|2    |2012-03-01 03:12:00  |Mike      |1         |
|3    |2012-03-01 08:51:00  |Art       |2         |
|4    |2012-03-02 01:20:00  |Kate      |2         |
|5    |2012-03-03 01:20:00  |Susan     |3         |
|6    |2012-03-05 07:46:00  |Sam       |4         |
===================================================
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Have you [tried anything](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: Take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/case.html even though this most likely means hardcoding the groups.